# Change a variable every n seconds

Tags: python-2.7

I am writing a script that needs to clear a variable every 5 seconds while the main program is running.

The following is my function

```
def clearBeepCounter():
while (checkforlowbatt == 1):
    sleep(lowbattdelay)
    beepscounted = 0
```

But using sleep halts the entire script. Can I keep resetting this variable as my main loop runs?

```
while (monitoringenabled == 1 & alert == 0):
sounddetected = wiringpi.digitalRead(19)
if (sounddetected == 1):
    beepscounted = beepscounted + 1
    lowbattbeepscounted = lowbattbeepscounted + 1 

if (beepscounted > 4):
    alert = 1
    q.put(2)

if (lowbattbeepscounted > 3):
    lowbatt = 1
    lowbattbeepscounted = 3 # dont want this to take up more memory if it isnt changed all day. 
    q.put(1)
sleep(refreshrate)
if (lowbatt == 1): print ("1")
elif (alert == 1): print ("2")
elif (lowbatt == 0 & alert== 0): print("0")
```

Is os.fork the way to go here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A thread might be the easiest way to do this using Python's [`threading`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html) module.

You can call `time.sleep` within a thread, and it will block only that thread.
There's a simple example [here](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Python_Programming/Threading). The key is then to use a global `beepscounted` variable, preferably with a [`Lock`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html#lock-objects) object guarding it for thread safety.

Comment: Can I still change the variables in the main program from that threaded function?

Comment: @Scu11y Yes. The variables you want to share between threads need to be (1) defined outside all functions they will be used in, and (2) defined as global within the functions the threads will be running. This just tells the function(s) that it should be looking at the global scope for the variable. Since you'll have multiple functions accessing/changing the variable, you'll want to use a `Lock` to avoid race conditions.

Comment: Sorry to ask this but the documentation is a bit confusing and so are some of the tutorials. `class clearcounter (threading.thread):
 def __init__(self, threadID, name, beepscounted)
 threading.Thread.__init__(beepscounted)
 



 def clearBeepCounter():
  while (checkforlowbatt == 1):
   sleep(lowbattdelay)
   beepscounted = 0`  

Is what I have so far but I'm unsure how to proceed from here? I also don't understand where to put the lock. If you could help me out with this I would be grateful.

Comment: I put an example [here](https://gist.github.com/ahota/298b579b2ce2844437677bc783030b66). You don't have to make a class unless you need to. I just made a thread with its target being your `clearBeepCounter` function. Notice how it uses global to access/alter the same variables as main, and it uses a lock to protect against multiple threads reading/writing a variable at the same time. [This](http://effbot.org/zone/thread-synchronization.htm) article is good for understanding basic use of locks and synchronization.

Comment: Thank you. This helped me alot. I appreciate the time spent making that file for me. It's useful to see it in that context. Thank you for your effort and accuracy.